# How do I convert my windows partition to a kvm virtual machine on Fedora?

Tags: windows, partitioning, virtual-machine, linux-kvm

I have a single hard drive with a windows partition and a fedora 19 partition. Is it possible to use a tool (e.g. `virt-p2v`) to convert the windows installation into a virtual machine on Fedora?

Disk details:

```
root@host / $ fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x787cf056

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1023999      510976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1024000   210739199   104857600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       210739200   211763199      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       211763200   976773167   382504984    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       211765248   976773119   382503936   8e  Linux LVM

root@host /root $ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   50G   32G   15G  69% /
devtmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    3.9G  2.7M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    3.9G  944K  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                    3.9G  148K  3.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda3                477M  120M  328M  27% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora-home  307G  200G   92G  69% /home
```

Comment: Use the tool you use to do what you want there are other tools well documented

Answer (score 1):

Converting partition from physical to image is trivial:

```
kvm-img /dev/sda1 /home/sda1.img
```

After that, please read http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-12/use-a-real-windows-7-partition-in-virtualbox-kvm-vmware-player-u.html article explained the rest.